# D3 Treemap v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pivottable.js

I am new to D3 and I am trying to convert a D3 Treemap from V3 to V4.
I have already read some information update the updated code but I can´t figure out to get it working.

The treemap is from the Pivottable.js D3 renderer.

This is the part.

```
    color = d3.scale.category10();
    width = opts.d3.width();
    height = opts.d3.height();
    treemap = d3.layout.treemap().size([width, height]).sticky(true).value(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });
    d3.select(result[0]).append("div").style("position", "relative").style("width", width + "px").style("height", height + "px").datum(tree).selectAll(".node").data(treemap.padding([15, 0, 0, 0]).value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    }).nodes).enter().append("div").attr("class", "node").style("background", function(d) {
      if (d.children != null) {
        return "lightgrey";
      } else {
        return color(d.name);
      }
    }).text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }).call(function() {
      this.style("left", function(d) {
        return d.x + "px";
      }).style("top", function(d) {
        return d.y + "px";
      }).style("width", function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px";
      }).style("height", function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px";
      });
    });
```

With D3 V4 I get some errors.

For example "d3.scale.category10" is not a function.
I replaced it with "d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)".

Then "sticky is not a function".
I replaced it with "tile(d3.treemapResquarify)".

But I also get "value is not a function" and "enter is not a function" which I can´t solve.
And I am not sure if have to change anything else to get it working with D3 V4.

This is my code for now. But it is not working.

```
    // Updated to V4
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    width = opts.d3.width();
    height = opts.d3.height();

    // Updated sticky for V4
    treemap = d3.treemap().size([width, height]).tile(d3.treemapResquarify).value(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });
    d3.select(result[0]).append("div").style("position", "relative").style("width", width + "px").style("height", height + "px").datum(tree).selectAll(".node").data(treemap.padding([15, 0, 0, 0]).value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    }).nodes).enter().append("div").attr("class", "node").style("background", function(d) {
      if (d.children != null) {
        return "lightgrey";
      } else {
        return color(d.name);
      }
    }).text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }).call(function() {
      this.style("left", function(d) {
        return d.x + "px";
      }).style("top", function(d) {
        return d.y + "px";
      }).style("width", function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px";
      }).style("height", function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px";
      });
    });
```

Can anyone help me with converting the rest this?

// Edit
Here is the working D3 v3 example fiddle. The d3_renderer is in the JS part.
https://jsfiddle.net/qntc8e7w/

And here is the same example but with D3 v4
https://jsfiddle.net/ybctz0a8/

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example to this question?

Comment: I have added an example in the original thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* The following code is written on the d3.v4.js plugin   */
                 treemap = d3.treemap().size([width, height]).paddingTop(15)
                .paddingInner(1);
                var div = d3.select(result[0]).append("div")
                .style("position", "relative")
                .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
                .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
                .style("left", margin.left + "px")
                .style("top", margin.top + "px");
    
                var root = d3.hierarchy(tree)
                root.sum(function(d) {
                    return d.value;
                });
                var treeObj = treemap(root);
                node = div.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
                .data(treeObj.descendants())
                .enter().append("div")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .style("left", (d) => d.x0 + "px")
                .style("top", (d) => d.y0 + "px")
                .style("width", (d) => Math.max(0, d.x1 - d.x0 - 1) + "px")
                .style("height", (d) => Math.max(0, d.y1 - d.y0  - 1) + "px")
                .style("cursor","pointer")
                .style("background", function(d) {
                    if (d.children != null) {
                        return "lightgrey";
                    } else {
                        return color(d.data.name);
                    }
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.name +" ( "+d.value +" )";
                })
```

Comment: I hope it will helps